# set allowautoredirect= false in custom HttpClientHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have custom HttpClientHandler like below

```
public class CustomHttpClientHandler : HttpClientHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

        request.Headers.Add("RequestSignature", Convert.ToBase64String(bytes));

        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

I want to set `allowautoredirect= false` in this CustomHttpClientHandler, how could i do this so it will apply to all request?

I am using it like this :

```
var client = new HttpClient(new CustomHttpClientHandler());
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.allowautoredirect?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the [`AllowAutoRedirect` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler?view=netframework-4.8#properties) within the constructor, like so

```cs
public class CustomHttpClientHandler : HttpClientHandler
{
    public CustomHttpClientHandler() : base() {
      // setup props
      AllowAutoRedirect = true;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
      // your stuff
    }
}
```